# Telnet to connect to my java server

Tags: linux, curl, telnet

I am trying to connect a client machine to my java server which is running on
139.78.141.234 on port 8080. The ip address for client is 172.168.100.248. I am using this command:

```
telnet 192.168.100.248 23456 http://139.78.141.234:8080/my.html
```

but I don't understand where am I possibly going wrong, because it doesn't display the error message rather displays:

```
Usage: telnet [-8] [-E] [-L] [-S tos] [-a] [-c] [-d] [-e char] [-l user]
    [-n tracefile] [-b hostalias ] [-r]
[host-name [port]]
```

When I use it with curl it works

```
curl -s http://139.78.141.234:9090/my.html
```

Comment: try `telnet 139.78.141.234 8080` and you'll get it.  But be careful that telnet uses TELNET protocol, which tries to negotiate some options with a binary format at the beginning (and this means you'll get garbage in the server side, just before any other data)

Answer (score 0):

The correct usage would be

```
telnet 139.78.141.234 8080
```

Note that you simply put the port after the hostname/IP address and ommit the protocol description, like http, as this is only needed for your browser.
And also ommit the path to website so /mysite.html . To retrieve some html file via telnet you need to speak http with the webserver. This means after being connected you can send GET requests to retrieve the website you want.

Comment: but I want 192.168.100.248  to connect to 139.78.141.234 at port 8080. Is that possible?

Comment: Yeah sure simply execute the above telnet command at the client with the IP 192.168.100.248 .

Comment: can I do that remotely, I do not have access to 192.168.100.248 machine

Comment: Do you have no physical access or are you not allowed to access the machine?

Comment: You can connect via ssh to your client remotely and then execute the telnet command there

Comment: Not allowed to, its an assignment. I am supposed to use telnet command

Comment: I guess then its part of the assignment that you figure it out, how to get the client connecting to the server. With the information you provided I would see no chance how, but bug exploiting. Depending on the class you take you won't be supposed to exploit things! As you have no logical access, so no account and nothing this seems the only chance, so I assume, that some information is missing.